# How to compute the sum over other sums in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

How can I compute the sum over other sums in Snowflake ? For example on this database:

```
id    Q1    Q2   Q3   Q4
1      1     2    3    4   
2      0     1    2    3   
3      3     2    1    0
```

I would like to obtain:

```
sumQ1   sumQ2   sumQ3   sumQ4  Total

 4       5      6       7       22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Q1) AS sumQ1
  , SUM(Q2) AS sumQ2 
  , SUM(Q3) AS sumQ3 
  , SUM(Q4) AS sumQ4
  , SumQ1 + SumQ2 + SumQ3 + SumQ4 AS Total 
FROM DT
```

I haven't tested it, but I think that should do the trick.

---

Edit:
To address the point made Simeon's answer. We create the example data in the OP:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DT (ID number, Q1 number, Q2 number, Q3 number, Q4 number);

INSERT INTO DT VALUES 
    (1,1,2,3,4),
    (2,0,1,2,3),
    (3,3,2,1,0);
```

Then, my answer above provides the following output:

```
SUMQ1   SUMQ2   SUMQ3   SUMQ4  TOTAL

 4       5      6       7       22
```

which is the output desired by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT sum(q1_sum) as q1, SUM(q2_sum) as q2, SUM(q3_sum) as q3, SUM(q4_sum) As q4 , (q1 +q2+q3+q4) total FROM 
(
  SELECT id, SUM(Q1) as q1_sum, SUM(Q2) as q2_sum, SUM(Q3) as q3_sum, SUM(Q4) as q4_sum FROM 
  (
  SELECT 1 as id, 1 as Q1 , 1 as q2, 2 as q3 , 1 q4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 as id, 1 as Q1 , 1 as q2, 1 as q3 , 3 q4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as id, 1 as Q1 , 1 as q2, 1 as q3 , 1 q4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as id, -1 as Q1 , 0 as q2, 1 as q3 , 2 q4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 as id, 2 as Q1 , 1 as q2, 1 as q3 , 1 q4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 as id, 1 as Q1 , 1 as q2, 0 as q3 , 2 q4
  ) GROUP BY id
)  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Roberts answer is very close, but should include the `id`, and thus the `GROUP BY` clause, like:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1, 1, 2, 3, 4),  
    (2, 0, 1, 2, 3),   
    (3, 3, 2, 1, 0)  
    v(id, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)
)
SELECT 
    ID
    ,SUM(Q1) AS sumQ1
    ,SUM(Q2) AS sumQ2 
    ,SUM(Q3) AS sumQ3 
    ,SUM(Q4) AS sumQ4
    ,SumQ1 + SumQ2 + SumQ3 + SumQ4 AS Total 
FROM data
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

gives:

| ID | SUMQ1 | SUMQ2 | SUMQ3 | SUMQ4 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 10 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 6 |

In snowflake you can refer to the prior defined output, in other SELECT columns (and in the WHERE clause). For a group by situation like this, as the `total` is defined by 4 inputs that are all aggregates, only `ID` needs to be mentioned in the group by. Which is super nice for keeps the SQL nice and tidy.

If you want the intermediate result table and the final row results. Change `GROUP BY 1` to `GROUP BY CUBE (1)` then you will get a totals as well.

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1, 1, 2, 3, 4),  
    (2, 0, 1, 2, 3),   
    (3, 3, 2, 1, 0)  
    v(id, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)
)
SELECT 
    ID
    ,SUM(Q1) AS sumQ1
    ,SUM(Q2) AS sumQ2 
    ,SUM(Q3) AS sumQ3 
    ,SUM(Q4) AS sumQ4
    ,SumQ1 + SumQ2 + SumQ3 + SumQ4 AS Total 
FROM data
GROUP BY CUBE (1) 
ORDER BY 1;
```

which gives, both sets of answers:

| ID | SUMQ1 | SUMQ2 | SUMQ3 | SUMQ4 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 10 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 6 |
|  | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 22 |

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I don't see anything in the OP that requires GROUP BY; and the output that my answer provides matches that which the OP requested, whereas it looks like your output isn't quite the same. Have I missed you point ?

Comment: @Robert. Ah. So true, i conflated the first set with the desired output